# How to select a record and only it's children with the highest date in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, children

Supose the table "Person" with the fields:

```
IdPerson, Name, Description.
```

And the table "FriendVisit" with

```
IdFriendVisit, Duration, TimeOfVisit, IdPerson
```

with a relation of 1 to n, where 1 person can have n FriendVisit.

I want to get all the persons with only the last visit in a linq to sql statment.

Somthing like:

```
var allpersons = this.ObjectContext.Person.Include(p=>p.FriendVisit.OrderBy(fv => fv.TimeOfVisit).FirstOrDefault())
```

In Reality I only need the Duration of the table FriendVisit and the Name of the table Person, but I don't know if this is relevant.

There is some form of doing it?

I tought of search the data from the children and then iclude the parent... but I would like to do it the "natural" way, call the parent and iclude the children.

ex:

```
var allVisits = this.ObjectContext.FriendVisit.Include(p=>p.Persons).OrderBy(fv => fv.TimeOfVisit).FirstOrDefault())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one:

In *query syntax*

```
var allPersons = from p in this.ObjectContext.Person
                 join f in this.ObjectContext.FriendVisit
                 on p.IdPerson equals f.IdPerson
                 group by new { p, f }
                 select new 
                 {
                     Name = p.Name;
                     Duration = f.OrderBy(x=>x.TimeOfVisit).Last().Duration
                 };
```

or in *fluent syntax*

```
var allPersons = this.ObjectContext.Person.Join(this.ObjectContext.FriendVisit,
                                                x=>x.IdPerson,
                                                y=>y.IdPerson
                                                (x,y)=> new { x, y }
                                         ).GroupBy(z=>z)
                                          .Select(x=> new 
                                           {
                                               Name = p.Name;
                                               Duration = f.OrderBy(y=>y.TimeOfVisit)
                                                           .Last()
                                                           .Duration
                                           });
```

Comment: I think that's I was looking for, now I try it, do you know if this can be achieved with lambda expressions?

Comment: Of course it can. Please give me few minutes to add teh corresponding code. Thanks from being patient.